# Arquitetura de computadores

Tags: arquitetura-computadores

Supondo um vídeo game básico formado por um processador e uma memória para armazenar os
processamentos do jogo e requisições de entrada de um *joystick*, e que a *ALU* é capaz de somar até três
requisições diferentes de entrada do joystick. A tabela abaixo mostra as codificações binárias sem flag, de
cada requisição do joystick.

```
Requisição Código Requisição Código
Up 0010101 A 1001010
Down 1010101 B 1110101
Left 1101010 C 1001001
Right 0011101 Start 0010110
```

a) De quanto deve ser a ALU (largura da variável w) para suportar as requisições do joystick de modo a
não haver estouro. A tabela abaixo mostra as codificações binárias sem flag de cada requisição do
joystick.

b) Como forma de diminuir os custos com a produção de um processador com menor capacidade
aritmética, ou seja, 7 bits, explique tecnicamente, qual seria o resultado prático no jogo, caso o
jogador faça uma combinação que cause um overflow. Discuta.

Comment: Enunciado interessante... Mas qual é a dúvida?

Comment: É um trabalho pra nós resolvermos?

Comment: Sim pessoal.. é uma questão de uma prova que achei interessante e coloquei aqui!

Comment: Eu já fiz, no caso postei aqui pelo desenvoltura da questão mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

a) 9 bits, que é a soma dos 3 maiores valores = 1 0011 0100

b) existem algumas coincidências na soma de três entradas, por exemplo:

```
      0 0001 0101 + 0 0100 1010 + 0 0101 0101 = 
    = 0 0001 0110 + 0 0100 1001 + 0 0101 0101 = 0 1011 0100
```

descartando o "overflow" e utilizando somente os 7 bits: 011 0100

Além disso, a soma das teclas UP, Start e C dão como resultado a tecla B, se for pressionada sozinha.

resultado: com 7 bits ou 9 bits a soma das teclas não é uma boa alternativa, pois há coincidência no resultado de algumas combinações.